# How to determine LOD threshold for significant QTL for analysis?

Tags: python, r, genome, rqt, plink-genomics

`    #Permutation test
operm10 <- scanone(boltbdh23_SPAD,method = "em",n.perm=1000,verbose = TRUE)
summary(operm10)
> summary(operm10)
LOD thresholds (1000 permutations)
lod
5%  3.05
10% 2.69
#Looking for qtls
#scanone em method
out1.em1<-scanone(boltbdh23_SPAD,method = "em")
plot(out1.em1, main=" EM SPAD",ylim=c(0,2),alternate.chrid = TRUE)
summary(out1.em1)#single largest from each chromosome

> summary(out1.em1)#single largest from each chromosome
> chr   pos   lod
> SC1_42581169  C1  96.5 0.449
> SC2_5981392   C2  77.4 0.849
> cC3.loc70     C3  70.0 1.768
> SC4_52892339  C4 143.6 0.705
> SC5_18771319  C5 136.1 0.409
> SC6_7166279   C6  21.3 1.594
> SC7_20481375  C7  21.8 0.486
> SC8_39579611  C8 130.9 0.523
> SC9_11060404  C9 160.8 1.614
> max(out1.em1)
> >  max(out1.em1)
> chr pos  lod
> cC3.loc70  C3  70 1.77`

As we know we need genome wide LOD threshold to determine the significant qtls but the 5% LOD value (here. 3.05) i am getting is way bigger than any other LOD score I am getting for every chromosome and maximum value (1.77). Help me how to correct this and what I am doing wrong.  `

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would seem to be more suitable for https://www.biostars.org/.